# Delphi 7, RegEx, один простой вопрос о match'ах в регулярке?

Tags: delphi, регулярные-выражения, delphi-7

Строка "check me please"
Регулярка (check)(me)

т.е. проMATCH'ить, одно должно идти в `match[1]`, другое в `match[2]`, у меня пишет что регулярка ничего вообще не находит, вот сэмпл:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var test1:string;
   t:TRegExpr;
begin
test1:='check me please';
t:=TRegExpr.Create;
try
t.Expression:='(check)(me)';
t.InputString:=test1;
if t.Exec then
 begin
 repeat
  showmessage('match[1]= '+t.Match[1]+' match[2]= '+t.Match[2]);
 until not t.ExecNext;
 end
 else
  showmessage('а нет ничего');
 finally
t.Free;
end;
end;
```

чего не так?

Comment: А как `(check)(me)` (без пробела между словами) должна ловить `check me please` (с пробелом)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так попробуй, чтобы разобраться:

```
test1:=' check me ';
...
t.Expression:=' (.*?) (.*?) ';
...
```

тут надо указывать не слова, которые хочешь выцепить, а то, как обособлены те части, которые тебе нужны. В данном случае слова в оригинале по бокам имеют пробелы, и по этому признаку ищутся совпадения.

В твоем примере будет так:

```
t.Expression:='(.*?) (.*?) ';
```

или так:

```
t.Expression:='(.*?) (.*?) please';
```

а вообще в интернетах много [информации](http://tdlite.ru/delphi/coregexpr/) по данному вопросу

PS. по поводу точного выдирания: тоже true

```
t.Expression:='(check) (me)';
```

тебе просто надо было пробел поставить между (check) и (me)

Comment: а что это даст? это не точный matching, это просто выдирание слов, явно не выход, а эту "информацию" я видел.

Comment: ага, вот на счет пробелов это да, разобрался.