# Извлечение текста из HTML-страницы регулярными выражениями

Tags: delphi, регулярные-выражения

Есть html страница

```
...
  <tr>
    <td class="basic-text" width="250">Type Allocation Holder</td>
    <td class="basic-text">Siemens</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="basic-text" width="250">Mobile Equipment Type</td>
    <td class="basic-text">Siemens S40</td>
  </tr>
...
```

Мне нужно из ее достать Siemens и S40 (или хотя бы Siemens S40) с помощью регулярных выражений.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я помню и сам парсил страницы на Делфи  - Делфи может работать с DOM. Возможно так оно будет лучше чем через регулярки

Comment: именно, TXMLDocument умеет

Comment: про TXMLDocument - судя по названию он будет работать только с XML документом. Но тут проблема может возникнуть в том что обрабатываемый HTML не будет являтся правильным XML - хотя тут могу ошибатся. Я в свое время загружал страницы через TWebBrowser и далее парсил через интерфейс

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите [данный ресурс](http://tdlite.ru/delphi/coregexpr/), вдруг, поможет.

И вообще, на похожий (хоть и отдаленно) вопрос я уже отвечал [ТУТ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/80510/delphi-7-regex-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BE-match-%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5).

Answer (score 0):

Поиск текста последних элементов <td> в рамках <tr>:

```
<td[^>]*>([^<]*)</td>\s*</tr>
```

Но эта конструкция хлипкая. Лучше и правда использовать HTML-парсер, потому как не к чему привязаться (Был бы для td-элементов с именами телефонов задан специфический класс, тогда другое дело).

Answer (score -1):

```
var
 FindMaster:TRegExpr;
.................
begin
    FindMaster:=TRegExpr.Create;
    FindMaster.Expression('Siemens S40');
    ...............................

end;
```

Comment: А если мы знаем, что ищем "Siemens S40", то зачем искать?

Comment: @Nofate Зато все сделано как написано в вопросе.